# Resize image view in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, imageview, resize

I need to programaticaly move an image view based on some conditions in my app. I do this by using CGAFfineTransform. However, after I move my view and try to resize it to fill in the resulting gap, the view doesn't resize. What can I do differently?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 44)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.width,
                        height: imageView.frame.height + 44)
```

Comment: (1) Since you are referencing frames, I'll assume you are not using auto layout. (2) Be careful about referencing any frames in `viewDidLoad`. It may be too early for that. (3) Why are you using `CAAffineTransform`? Why not simply change the frame? You can even animate such a thing - but again, not in `viewDidLoad`. (4) What do you mean by *"fill in the resulting gap"*? It makes little sense. Maybe you need to be a bit more descriptive on *what* you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm using autolayout, but depending on the app state there will or wont be an additional button. If its absent I would like the image view to resize to fill in the gap that is left by this button. Setting the frame does nothing, while using the CGAffineTransform repositions the element.

Comment: Yes, frames *shouldn't* mean anything if you are using auto layout. And also yes, `CGAffineTransform` screws with frames. So maybe I need to focus on two things I asked to see if I can help. (1) What exactly are you trying to do? (2) Could you post your full code on the layout? I don't think you need to post the conditional code, just the (a) layout with and without this button, (b) the view controller events they are wrapped in, and - maybe - (c) the UIImageView's `contentMode` if you think it matters. (But please, edit your question. It helps others instead of posting a comment.)

Comment: basically i dont know how to programmatically resize a view that has autolayout constraints set

Comment: That's a *very* different question than what you have here. TL;DR? Yes, you can resize a view. I'm short on time right now, but here's my recommendation. (1) Delete this question - I don't think it's a ding against you - and create a new one. (2) In the new one stress that you wish to programmatically change a constant of a constraint. From the look of things, I think you are trying to change a vertical constant - top, bottom, maybe even height - and not a horizontal one - leading, trailing, left, right, maybe width. (3) Be as complete as possible on what constraints you already have....

Comment: .... particularly if the constraints are set in the storyboard. (4) Before that, do a search on *"[Swift] change constraint programmatically"*. I tried but couldn't find a good example to link here, sorry, my time is limited right now. You may have better luck. (5) The basic concept is you need to explicitly *name* the constraint you are trying to change as a variable, then in the right place - `viewDidLoad` can work - change that variable's `.constant' value. Then if needed, animate the change.

Comment: thanks, I figured it out based on what you said. All I needed to do was one line of code and the auto-layout then updated all other views on screen. Which is pretty neat I guess.

saveRunButtonBottomConstraint.constant = -44

this just moved the button down by 44 pts.

if you want to add an answer I'll accept it as correct

Comment: While I appreciate the offer, I think it's too misleading, as the actual issue isn't easy to find in your question. Glad I could be of help though!